# Invertibility of Moment Generating Functions Equal on Small Interval

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, moment-generating-functions

I am taking a statistics course right now and we're using Hogg, McKean and Craig's *Introduction to Mathematical Statistics* (2013).

How do you prove Thm 1.9.1:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables with moment generating functions
>   $M_X$ and $M_Y$, respectively, existing in open intervals about $0$.
>   Then $F_X(z)=F_Y(z)$ for all $z\in\mathbb{R}$ if and only if
>   $M_X(t)=M_Y(t)$ for all $t\in(-h,h)$ for some $h>0$.

The book says to look at Chung (1974) - *A Course in Probability Theory*, but I have browsed through the book and I couldn't find the statement or the proof (I looked at Chapter 6, which deals with characteristic functions). I have looked online but could not find the proof. My statistics professor refuses to talk about the proof, even in office hours, saying it is "outside the scope of this course". I have taken upper-level undergraduate courses in real analysis, complex analysis and probability. I learned about Laplace transforms in lower-level differential equations.

Answer (score 1):

The moment generating function is defined by
$$M_X(t) := \int \exp(Xt) \, \mathrm{d} \mathbb{P}$$
for $t \in \mathbb{R}$, assuming $\exp(Xt) \in L^1$. This definiton makes also sense for all $t \in \mathbb{C}$ and defines a holomorphic function. Thus, your statement is a direct consequence of the identity theorem for holomorphic functions.

Comment: Hmm. But for many functions, there exist $t\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\exp(Xt)\not\in L^1$. How do you deal with that?

Comment: The above argument also works, if $\exp(Xt) \in L^1$ for $t \in (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$. Then $M_X(z)$ can be defined on $\{z \in \mathbb{C} \, \colon \, |\mathrm{Re}(z)| < \varepsilon \}$ and is holomorphic on this domain. Your question is also related to the so-called 'Hamburger moment problem': Is the distribution of $X$ uniquely determined by the moments? In general, the answer is in general no. However, 'Carleman's Condition' is sufficient, see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleman%27s_condition).

Comment: Why must $M_X(z)$ be holomorphic on this domain? I tried using the Dominated Convergence Theorem as in the proof of equality on $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ of $M_X$ and its MacLaurin series, but I couldn't get it to work out.

Comment: You can show that $x \mapsto x^n \exp(xt)$ is uniformly integrable in some neighbourhood of $t \in (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$, using the estimate $1+|z|^n/n! \leq \exp(|z|)$. This implies (by the dominated convergence theorem) that this function is $C^\infty$ and also holomorphic. (The last argument is also known as "the theorem on parameter integrals".) One can also formulate an theorem on paramter integrals for holomorphic functions (with easier condition) by using the Cauchy integral formula.